# How do I get the value of a btc address transaction with pybitcoin tools?

Tags: python, pybitcointools

Lets say that I execute the code below when the user accesses the deposit page.

```
my_private_key = random_key()
my_public_key = privtopub(my_private_key)
my_address = pubtoaddr(my_public_key)
```

And I let the user deposit into my_address.

How would I obtain the value of the users deposit into my_address?

Comment: Note that you seem to have asked the same question here, https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/78180/using-pybitcointools-to-get-the-value-for-a-certain-transaction
Please don't ask the same question multiple times or use multiple accounts

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `unspent` command to find unspent outputs sent to that address, or `history` to see all outputs to that address whether they are spent or not. Note that it relies on public APIs to read the blockchain for transactions.